# Can I send information in url similar to get method in a form using AJAX?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I want to send data to another page like using get method in a form when submitting form using php  for example when I send  data to a page test.php
I want it become like test.php?username=something here....

```
 let headers = {
    method: "GET",
    data: {
      username: "something here"
    },
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    }
  };
  let data = await fetch('test.php', headers);
```

I want after I send that data to the test.php   the $_GET  has 'username' => something here

Note that this code is written inside an async function

Comment: All you need is the last line and `'test.php?username=' + someVar` instead of `'test.php'`

Comment: So add a querystring to the url.....

Comment: lol I am so dumb sorry thank you guys  @ChrisG and epascarello